# XSLT 2.0 - Move existing child nodes to newly created Node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<xsl:template match="BaseNode">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
         <None attr1="0" attt2="1" attr2="0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input A']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input B']"/>
         </None>
      </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>
```

Above is the XSLT that I try to use for Moving existing child nodes to newly created Node. 
That rule is creating the new Node and also copies the nodes as children. 
The problem is that I still have the old Elements in the parent Node. 
What I want is like a cut and paste operation , not copy paste. 
Thank you in advance for your help.

Input XML

```
<ParentNode attr1="1" attr2="2">
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicEnum attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
        <Pair Key="0" Value="a"/>
        <Pair Key="1" Value="b"/>
        <Pair Key="2" Value="c"/>
        <Pair Key="3" Value="d"/>
    </BasicEnum>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
</ParentNode>
```

Desired Output

```
<ParentNode attr1="1" attr2="2">
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicEnum attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
        <Pair Key="0" Value="a"/>
        <Pair Key="1" Value="b"/>
        <Pair Key="2" Value="c"/>
        <Pair Key="3" Value="d"/>
    </BasicEnum>
    <NewElement>
        <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
        <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    </NewElement>
</ParentNode>
```

Obtained Output with my Rule

```
<ParentNode attr1="1" attr2="2">
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicInt attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicEnum attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
        <Pair Key="0" Value="a"/>
        <Pair Key="1" Value="b"/>
        <Pair Key="2" Value="c"/>
        <Pair Key="3" Value="d"/>
    </BasicEnum>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    <NewElement>
        <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
        <BasicDouble attr1="1" attr2="2"/>
    </NewElement>
```

Comment: Please share the input XML and the desired output XML so that the XSLT shared can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Jsut guessing: try removing the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` element.

Comment: By removing <xsl:apply-templates/> the rest of the child nodes that I need will not get copied.

Comment: Please don't tag the question XSLT 2.0 if you are using an XSLT 1.0 processor (and don't intend to upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

Please give the XML example for more clearification. 
You can try this:

```
<xsl:template match="BaseNode">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except (//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input A'],//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input B'])"/>
         <None attr1="0" attt2="1" attr2="0">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input A']"/>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//BaseNode/BasicDouble[@Descr = 'Input B']"/>
         </None>
      </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If I try this I get the following error: FatalError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: 'except', '(', '/', '/',

Comment: If the error is because your processor works on XSLT 1.0, try to replace the above 4th line with the following:
<xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::BasicDouble[@Descr='Input A' or @Descr='Input B'])]"/>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. This works just fine. I think that I don't have enough reputation on the site to accept the answer., but I will upvote